# Virtualbox - Automatically return to snapshot

Tags: virtualbox

I've been trying for quite a while now to get the following thing to work - without success. I know that my approach is a bit of a dirty hack, so I'm always open for suggestions about how to do this in a better way.

We're running VirtualBox on Linux machines in a school environment. There are a couple of applications that absolutely need to be run under Windows, which is why there's no way around VirtualBox (forget wine!). So we put a Virtual Machine image on every local hard drive which the students can run if they need to. This image really ought to be "read only" in one way or another. Obviously, even running the machine will make changes to that image, so we need a mechanism that automatically reverts those changes. We're somewhat flexible about when this is supposed to happen. To me, doing this at each reboot seems to be the best approach but I wouldn't mind it being done at, say, logoff.

Right now we're using rsync on the image every time the computer boots which works as long as the virtual machine isn't started until that process is finished. Despite the fact that it works, it's a pain for the administrator as it may lead to various kinds of errors that are hard to reproduce, so there must be a better way.

My idea was to use a snapshot which I automatically revert to. Since simply deleting the Snapshot VDIs won't work, I wanted to create a "template snapshot vdi" (around 180MB) which is copied to a world writeble location (e.g. /tmp) at boot time. I know there's still a race condition but copying 180MB on a local hard drive should be significantly faster and predictable than rsyncing some 15GB. I then configure the virtual machine to use that snapshot.

Doing this VirtualBox produces error

Parent UUID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} doesn't match UUID {12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012} in the xml file.

A possible cause is [this issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14058) with VirtualBox, though I'm not sure about this.

What came to my mind right now while writing those lines is using a script to copy/rsync the snapshot VDI template to the "right" path within the home directory just before the machine is being started by that script.

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not change the type of the disk to immutable? https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2011/08/31/making-auto-resetting-virtualbox-machines/

Comment: Because I didn't know that option even exists... I haven't tried it, yet, but it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't being sarcastic - just trying to help.

Comment: Oh, don't worry, I didn't think you were. I really appreciated your help. I'm feeling a bit sheepish now because of all the time I've wasted on this so far. :)